# Seam FORM problem

Tags: java, servlets, seam, web.xml

I have a simple form method...

```
<form method="POST" action="j_security_check">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>Name:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="j_username" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr style="margin-top: 10px;">
            <td>Password:</td>
            <td><input type="password" name="j_password" /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td colspan="2"><input type="submit" value="Go" /></td>
        </tr>                   
    </table>
</form>
```

This page is in `login.xhtml`.

When the user enters the wrong information it re-routes me to `j_security_check.html`, and when it does, it loses all of it's styling. Is there a way around this?

Resource to make login appear:

```
<login-config>
    <auth-method>CLIENT-CERT,FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/login.seam</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/login.seam</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
```

In addition, accessible data is:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
        <web-resource-name>Accessible Data</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/login</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/a4j/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/css/*</url-pattern>
        <url-pattern>/img/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
</security-constraint>
```

When I look inside the view source, it seems that the login page source has all the CSS and attributes loaded, but the `j_security_check` page doesn't.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can you post the j_security_check.html file then? Why does it not have styling?

Comment: Provide all of the HTML for both files.

Comment: Include the same style sheet on j_security_check html. Or... include more detail.

Comment: If you want the form to submit to the same page, set `action=""`

Comment: You need to give some more information.  It j_security_check.html reading back in the login page?  Perhaps the paths are incorrect or it is not reading the style in the new page if it's not the same code?

Comment: I don't have a j_Security_check file which is wierd o.O

Comment: @gamebooka, if i do action="" then i can't login

Comment: j_security_check is just a form for active directory

Comment: Most likely your css is in a separate file, and the round trip is messing up the path to the css file. You can check in Firebug or similar to see the path being used to attempt to fetch the css file.

Comment: That is true, good call. I will take a better looka ti t, but any idea why it goes from

http://localhost:7005/login -> http://localhost:7005/j_security_check 

i dont have j_security_check

Comment: What's the URL of the secured resource you are requesting that causes the login page to appear in the first place?

Comment: Posted, thank you so much alohci

Comment: any idea? alochi on fixing this?

Comment: Sorry, not really. It looks a little odd that your css files are secured, since they'll not work until the user's logged in. You really need to track the http in firebug to see what's happening to the css requests and responses. Are the requests sent? Do they return 200 or 404 status code. If 200, what is in the file? (BTW, on SO, if you want to let someone know that you've replied to a comment, put @ before their user name in your reply - e.g. @Alohci)

Comment: Also, if you're saying that the `<link` line to the css file is not in HTML of the response to the j_security_check url, that would imply something amiss in the configuration behind the /login.seam url. That may be enough to ask a new question on authentication in seam. May sure you tag the question with java, seam and authentication and then it's much more likely to come to the attention of the experts in that area.

Comment: @Alohci this makes me sad... apparently, you can't style it :( 

http://www.coderanch.com/t/448131/JSF/java/forms-authentication-security-check-JSF

Comment: at least using rich faces and etc, you need just plain html/css

Comment: @Kevin, it would be lovely if you could make the title of your question more precise.

Comment: @stakx sorry, I wasn't so sure, but indeed it isn't using JSF, but rather its more of seam, so I just did HTML form. Thanks though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://www.coderanch.com/t/448131/JSF/java/forms-authentication-security-check-JSF has the answer

it is not possible to style your page using JSF, if you are doing j_Security_check

Comment: It works for me. Your problem is caused by something else. Too bad that you didn't tag this question using `jsf` from the beginning on and give it a bad title. I totally missed this question.

Answer (score 0):

The `action="j_security_check"` attribute on the form guarantees that he submit button will send you to j_security_check. What you probably want to do is have your handler for j_security_check redirect back to `login.xhtml` to let the user try entering their credentials again.

Comment: hmm how would that be done? do I make a j_security_check.html that just redirects me back to login.xhtml?

Comment: Well, in order to have a user log in, you're probably going to need a server component that checks username/password against a database. There aren't many good options for doing this entirely in HTML. Is there a server technology like PHP or Django or anything involved in what you're building?

Comment: @sblom - the server technology is almost certainly Java. Tomcat or a similar servlet container. j_security_check is part of the container. If the container config (web.xml) is set up correctly, it will forward the request back to the login page if the login credentials are not satisfactory.

Comment: alohci is correct. it is web.xml but my error and login page are both set to login.xhtml... weird thing is. when you log in invalid then you are redirected to some sort of j_security_check page. any idea?